# Enable/Disable Parameters based on Boolean

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters, tool-validation

I'm working in model builder and I have a boolean parameter that determines which of two processes run.  Right now, all of the parameters for both processes show up when I run the model.  Is there a way to only enable the parameters that are necessary for the one process that will run based on the boolean?

Comment: I think it would be worth looking into tool validation to try and do this.

Comment: You may need to have a Python script tool (which supports tool validation) wrapped around your model tool.